# obtain the sum of all the elements in two lists in python

Tags: python

I have two lists

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
b=[5,6,7]
```

What I want is to find the sum of each element in both the lists and store the sum to another variable, i.e

```
1+2+3+4+5+6+7=28
```

and store it to any variable.

**My code:**

```
for i in range(0,len(od)):
    s=s+od[i]
v=s
for i in range(0,len(ed)):
    v=v+ed[i]
print(v)
```

I have found the sum by this method. Is there any other method which will be shorter and more pythonic?

Comment: `v=sum(a)+sum(b)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum

You could write this code as:

```py
v = sum(od) + sum(ed)
```

EDIT: As a side note, the way you're doing item iteration is not 'pythonic' as well. On most languages you access array items using indexes (the `[i]` part), but on python, the ideal way to iterate an array is by getting the values directly.

So, if you wanted to follow the same structure as the initial code, the 'pythonic' way to write it would be something like this:

```py
result = 0

for value in od:
    result += value

for value in ed:
    result += value

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

> The sum() function returns a number, the sum of all items in an iterable.

Basically you just have to add the sum of both of your lists

```
v = sum(od) + sum(ed)
```

Answer (score 0):

Addition to @João Haas Answer you can process in a different way also. contact a list first then compute the sum

```
v = sum(od + ed)
```

Comment: This would end up generating a new list just to be thrown away later. It works, but there's an additional overhead.